# Linking drop-down selection to slicer

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop-down list (Excel data-validation) with the same options as a slicer (both from different sources).

How do I link my drop-down list selection to my slicer?

Nothing is recorded when I make a selection on a drop-down list.

E.g.

```
Drop-down list: Area 1, Area 2, Area 3  
Slicer: Area 1, Area 2, Area 3
```

Goal: If I select Area 3 from my drop-down list, my slicer should have Area 3 selected too.

Comment: What kind of dropdown do you have? Is it on an Excel sheet or on a form? Is it an ActiveX control or a Form control? Or is it a Data Validation Dropdown?

Comment: It is a data validation dropdown in excel.

Answer (score 0):

You need a event routine for `Change` that is triggered whenever the cell where the dropdown lives is changed, and a routine that changes the slicer.

Put the following code to the worksheet object in the VBA-Editor (not to a new module). Change the cell address (in the example it is `E10` to the cell you are using). If you have more than one slicer in your workbook, you have to change the index to `SlicerCaches` to the one you want to modify (as usual in VBA, you can use the index number or the name).

```
Option Explicit
' The Event routine    
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address(False, False) = "E10" Then
        SelectSlicerItem ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(1), Target.value
    End If
End Sub
```

The following routine can be put either below the event routine or into a module. Note that if the `itemText` is not found in the slicer, all items will be selected.

```
Sub SelectSlicerItem(sc As SlicerCache, itemText As String, Optional defaultItem As String = "")
    Dim si As SlicerItem, found As Boolean
    found = False
    sc.ClearManualFilter
    For Each si In sc.SlicerItems
        ' Debug.Print si.Caption, si.value
        If si.Caption <> itemText Then
            si.Selected = False
            found = True
        End If
    Next si
    If Not found And defaultItem <> "" Then SelectSlicerItem sc, defaultItem
End Sub
```

**Edit:** Changed `SelectSlicerItem` to deal with default item.

Comment: Thank you FunThomas. Few more questions if possible pls. (1) My dropdown list is on another worksheet. I tried using a cell on my slicers worksheet to reference the dropdown list to simplify things but it doesn't work. I believe this is because Worksheet_Change requires user input. Are suggestions on this? (2) I have 3 slicers set up and your code works if itemText is found in all 3 slicers. However, as you mentioned, all items will be selected if itemText is not found. Any suggestions on how to select "(blank)" if itemText is not found instead? Many thanks!

Comment: **(1)** The event routine must be in the sheet where the dropdown lives. **(2)** I added an (optional) default parameter, call the routine with `"(blank)"` as third parameter. But again, if that default option is also missing in the slicer, all items will be selected - that's the nature of a slicer.